# Response redirect stays on same link (WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Im using Webforms throught C#

When the users does a certain action it might be redirected to another link, which is not working atm (it was before and i cant rollback the project since idh tfs or github)

The user is on this site:

```
localhost:53145/VistaUsuario.aspx
```

When it users fills the form and click accept the code behind is:

```
Session["user"] = txtDominio.Text;

Response.Clear();
Response.Redirect("FormOrden.aspx");
```

When it does the action it's redirected to the same link adding this parameters :

```
localhost:53145/VistaUsuario.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fFormOrden.aspx
```

This is the code behind "FormOrden.aspx"

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string usuario = (string)Session["user"];

            if (usuario != null)
            {
                this.MostrarDatos();

            }
            else
            {
                this.DoSomethingElse();
            }
        }
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have Authentication enabled in your web.config.  Your session is not authenticated so any attempt to go to another page goes back to the authentication page, which happens to be your current page (likely default.aspx).

The reason you see ReturnUrl="%2fFormOrden.aspx is because that's how Forms Authentication handles redirects after logging in.

Basically, you try to hit a page that requires authentication and are not authenticated.  Forms Authentication redirects the request to the login page.  Upon Logging in you make a call to FormsAuthentication to RedirectFromLogin page and it goes to the page specified in the ReturnUrl to go back to where the user was trying to go.

Either finish your authentication workflow, or turn off forms authentication in your web.config.

Comment: the authentication was working fine before, but i had to turn it off now (might check this later). Thanks a lot for ur answer :)